# Cannot convert JSON(type string) to ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, json, type-conversion

My code is as following:

Class Message():

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Message extends Validatable {

    private static final String[] valid_commands = {"EXCHANGEKEY"};

    private final String command;
    public Message(String command){this.command = command;}
    public String getCommand() {return command;}
    @Override
        public boolean isValid() {
        for (String c : valid_commands) {
            if(c.equals(this.command))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {return new Gson().toJson(this);}
}
```

Class subMessage():

```
import java.security.PublicKey;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class subMessage extends Message{
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String,PublicKey> keyList;
    public ExchangeKeyList(ConcurrentHashMap<String,PublicKey> keyList){
        super("EXCHANGEKEY");
        this.keyList = keyList;
    }
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String,PublicKey> getKeyList() {
        return keyList;
    }
}
```

The problem is, after I use
     `gson = new GSON();`
and if I set
    `String JSON = gson.toJson(subMessage keyListToJson);`
then I set
    `subMessage keyListFromJson = gson.FromJson(JSON,subMessage.class);`
,it will return an error.
I'm so confused since keyListToJson here is a valid subMessage instance,it should be able to get a valid keyListFromJson instance as well. But it apprently does not, I'm not sure why?
Can anyone help me please?

The error message is as following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.security.PublicKey. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:226)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:210)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
at EZShare.server.WorkerThread.processKeyExchange(WorkerThread.java:411)
at EZShare.server.WorkerThread.reception(WorkerThread.java:127)
at EZShare.server.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:70)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Interface can't be instantiated! Interface name: java.security.PublicKey
    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator.assertInstantiable(UnsafeAllocator.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator.access$000(UnsafeAllocator.java:31)
    at com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator$1.newInstance(UnsafeAllocator.java:49)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:223)
    ... 18 more

Comment: please share stack trace

Answer (score 1):

As per Gson documentation -

> If the object that your are serializing/deserializing is a
>   `ParameterizedType` (i.e. contains at least one type parameter and may
>   be an array) then you must use the `toJson(Object, Type)` or
>   `fromJson(String, Type)` method.

So you should use below code for parsing json:

```
Type subMessageList = new TypeToken<List<subMessage>>() {}.getType();
List<subMessage> target = new LinkedList<subMessage>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(target, subMessageList);
List<subMessage> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, subMessageList );
```

For Reference - https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't post error message. In my code I think I did use 
    toJson(String,Type) and     fromJson(String,Type)method,because I set     "Type" here as    "subMessage.class",which will return type of that class.

Comment: May be you are using the wrong methods, you should use the overloaded method with second argument Type, since your class contains a hashmap, see my answer above.